# Access 2007 wont open in 2013 just gives errors saying not compatible

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

This is my first attempt at a big access project so please be gentle :)

I have created a database in Access 2007 on my works PC and it is a .accdb format files.  I tried to open it in Access 2013 on my home PC but all I get is compatibility errors and when I eventually get through these it shows it as empty.  If I open in 2007 again all is ok.

Comment: have you checked [why-wont-access-2013-open-an-mdb-file](http://superuser.com/questions/488783/why-wont-access-2013-open-an-mdb-file) ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Microsoft Office!

Microsoft in their "wisdom" have disabled access to older versions of Access projects!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj618413.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Access 2013 will open files in the Access 2000 format or the 2000-2003 format, both have the MDB extension.  In Access 2007, you should be able to uses Tools/Database Utilities/Convert to convert your Access 2007 ACCDB file to one of the older formats.

It will be easiest if you just leave the file in one of those older MDB formats and you'll be able to go back and forth without converting each time.  It's not likely that you'll need anything that isn't available in the MDB formats to complete your project.