# Access 2013 file to open in Access 2003

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010, microsoft-access-2003

I made `Access Form` which was working fine in **Access 2013 and Access 2007** until I add some new features(I don't remember what) to it.

After adding them, it keeps giving me error `"Unrecognize file format"` when I try to run it in Access 2003. Meanwhile it runs fine in Access 2013.

I want to ask if there exists some software to convert Access 2013 file to Access 2003? Or is there any way make it compatible to 2003? When I Save As 2003 file it don't because of some added features.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply create a new access database and save it as access 2000-2003 file format.
2. After doing it simply go to EXTERNAL DATA available in menu bar.
3. Click Access and select the file you want to import (i.e. the one which is not opening in 2003 format).
4. It will ask you for the file destination.
5. Select the first option "import tables,queries,forms,macros and modules" and click OK.
6. In the next dialogue box, simply select all the objects(tables,forms,queries,reports etc) you want.

It's done...

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing from another question on superuser:

> Access 2013 supports **Access 2000 and later versions through Access 2010**, and requires databases made in earlier versions to be converted using an earlier version of Access - [Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954.aspx)

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/488783/why-wont-access-2013-open-an-mdb-file)

So it would seem your issue lies elsewhere with whatever features you might have added. Since you can't remember them we won't really be able to help you, but the above should rule out your compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the upgrade is a one way deal with Access.  Unless you can restore from a backup you won't be able to run on 2003 any more.

(I like 2003 and still use it everyday, even though I bought 2007 thinking it would be an improvement.  Before trying to upgrade I was careful to backup.  Then when 2007 didn't work out so well, because I hated their new menu structure, it wasn't too hard to roll back into 2003, .. which does everything I need.  I haven't tried 2010 yet.  I wonder if it fixed some of what they messed up in the ribbon jump of 2007.)

Comment: For what it's worth, the ribbon interface in Access 2010 is *much* improved over Access 2007.